# Jquery Select next sibling tab with condition

Tags: jquery, tabs, telerik

I currently have this layout:

```
      _______________________________________________________
      |         X|         X|        X | <display:|        X |
 _____|__________|__________|          |___none>__|__________|_______________________
 |                                                                                   |
 |                                                                                   |
 |                                                                                   |
```

My plan is when I press 'X', is for the tab to:

- Inject style `display: none;`
- Open The next tab/make next tab active.

I'm currently using the Jquery:

```
    $('.k-image').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().css("display","none");
    });
```

To 'close' the tab.I.e. Pressing the 'X' button closes the tab.

And:

```
    $('#allocations').click(function (e) {
        $('.k-item').removeClass("k-state-active");
        $("[aria-controls=tabMain-2]").css("display", "initial");
    });
```

to open one.

What I want is for the 'tab' and 'Content' to go to the *next available tab* when i 'close' a tab. This means to loop through the tabs, find which is 'not display: none' and display it.

How can this be achieved using Jquery (select the next sibling in which display is not none ***and*** if it reaches the end, then start over from beginning)?

Please note I'm using telerik tabstrip, and so here is a view of the page inspector:

[image]

For visibility issues, I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/eu0fe7pv/) in order to make the generated markup easier to read.

**Please note**

I can close ony of the tabs, it doesn't have to be the active tab that i'm closing.

Comment: use .after in jquery and change it to active .. or trigger click on it

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef that doesn't really answer my question - i'm looking to select the *sibling of which hasn't got an attribute*. I can do the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be changed:

```
$(this).parent().parent().css("display", "none");
```

To this:

```
var $closed = $(this).closest(".k-item").css("display", "none");
```

Once you get a hold of closed item, use `.nextAll()` function:

```
var $next = $closed.nextAll(":visible:first");
if ($next.length === 0) {
    $next = $closed.siblings(":visible:first");
}
```

Not tested but I gave it a try here: http://jsfiddle.net/salman/eu0fe7pv/1/

Answer (score 1):

To grab siblings with JQuery, you have some nifty selectors such as [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) that should be useful to you. There's also [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) if you want to start at the first tab if the last tab is closed.

So `$(this).next()` should give you the item that directly follows the object that's currently selected.

If you want to expand it even further, there are also functions like [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) which will give you every sibling that matches a selection, or [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) which will give you every sibling until a selection is met.

As for checking whether or not a tab is visible. There are a couple ways to go about doing that. You could use the function [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to see if the object has a class or style applied to it. In your case you want something like:

`if($(this).is(':visible')) {
    //Do something
}`

[Here's a JSFiddle I made](http://jsfiddle.net/ozo012uf/) that sounds like it does about what you want. Also here's a Code snippet if you just want to see what it does.

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    
    self.slideToggle(); // Slose the box.
    $('.active').removeClass('active'); // Remove all instances of the active class.
    
    self.nextAll(':visible').first().addClass('active'); // Set the first sibling that's visible to active.
    
    if(self.html() === $('.box').last().html()){  // If it's the last box, start over.
        $('.box').first().addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.box {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box">2</div>
<div class="box active">3</div>
<div class="box">4</div>
<div class="box">5</div>
```